# What is the proper way to name a bundle identifier.?

Tags: android, mobile-application, bundle-identifier

As there are so many ways to create an app bundle-identifier, which or what is the professional or proper way to be considered while naming an bundle-identifier.?

I used to follow this

```
com.companyname.appname
```

Is there any better way to do this or it depends.?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `com.companyname.appname` is the proper way.

To remember it, think of it as a DNS name in reverse.

Comment: Thanks, but while going through the "Play Store" and "App Store", I kind of found bundle-identifiers with os/platforms something like "com.companyname.appname.mac" or "app name.ios". Any explanations for that. For a better understanding.!

Comment: Again, using a DNS analogy: `mail.marketing.acme.com` and `www.marketing.acme.com` is a mail server and a www server for the marketing department in `acme.com`, i.e. two platforms for interacting with the marketing marketing department.
By the same token, imagine `acme.com` builds a marketing app, it might be built for different platforms. In this case, the naming `com.acme.marketingapp.ios` and `com.acme.marketingapp.android` would be sensible.

Comment: Interesting.! Now I do have a clear idea on naming a bundle-identifier. Honestly thanks a lot to respond even after this question has been marked as duplicate. :) keep spreading love.! Thanks again.